# No rule to make target error halfway down the make

Tags: makefile

On a Leopard Mac mini (PowerPC) I'm trying to compile Apple-GCC-3.3 which I got from https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/gcc_os/gcc_os-1819.tar.gz

./configure gets completed w.o. any error but make gives the following errors:

When input only "make" it says

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all', needed by `default'.  Stop.
```

When input make -f Makefile, the make starts fine but somewhere halfway down the process it stops with:

```
gcc  tclAppInit.o -L/Users/macmini/Downloads/gcc_os-1819/tcl/unix -ltcl8.0  -lc \-o tclsh
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make: *** [all-expect] Error 2
```

For this type of error, it's said that the tar might be dropping long filenames during the untar operation but I tried with different versions of tar such as 1.14, 1.27 and the error is the same.

What should I do? Thanks.
!(http://i.hizliresim.com/Kl9rRJ.png)
(Just in case you may wonder why I want to compile GCC-3.3, it's because it's needed to compile GIMP on PowerPC Macs)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turned really hard to compile GCC-3.3 from source, so I made it easy and installed it from XCode 3.1 DVD, under the Packages directory where GCC-3.3.pkg was present.
Now the GIMP can be compiled.

Summary: It's a good idea to install the Apple's compiler group of programs from the XCode DVD.

Thanks.